# Notation and name for iterative matrix-vector multiplication in sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to find a name for the following operation and have not had any success Googling.

Let $\boldsymbol{A}^{[1]} \boldsymbol{x}^{[1]} = \boldsymbol{b}^{[1]}$ denote one iteration of matrix-vector multiplication. Next, the elements of $\boldsymbol{A}^{[1]}$ are modified in some way to produce a new matrix $\boldsymbol{A}^{[2]}$. Now the output, $\boldsymbol{b}^{[1]}$, is multiplied by this new matrix so that the next iteration is $\boldsymbol{A}^{[2]} \boldsymbol{x}^{[2]}$, where $\boldsymbol{x}^{[2]} = \boldsymbol{b}^{[1]}$.

In summary, this is repeated matrix-vector multiplication where the matrix changes in a sequence and the output in the previous round is the input for the next round.

My questions:

1. Is there a name for this iterative process so I can search and learn more about its properties?
2. What is the best way to represent this process in notation? I do not think using the $\prod$ operator is sufficient here as it does not, to my knowledge, indicate matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Is [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) what you want? (maybe not, since the matrix doesn't really change there.)

As for notation, you can define a sequence of $A^t$ and $v^t$ and write out their recursive relationship.